# How activate a groupbox with a radioButton in visual Prolog

Tags: visual-prolog

predicates
onRadioButton_PlumasStateChanged : radioButton::stateChangedListener.
clauses
onRadioButton_PlumasStateChanged(_Source, _OldState, _NewState):-
if _NewState = radioButton::selected then
gb_Aves:setEnabled(true)
else
gb_Aves:setEnabled(false).

this es my code and when i tried to build send me syntax error. I dont know why.